Optimize query with min
I have table a where I have
Transaction_id (not unique, for one transaction it could be many string value for other status), status (for example A001,A002,A003),  string value. I want to join to my main query only this string value which is assigned to the lowest number. I wrote query:
With data as 
(select transaction_id, step_id, string_value 
   from global_data gd 
  inner join (Select transaction_id, min(substr(status,2,3)) as mini 
                from global_data gd1 
               group by deal_no) as ls 
    on ls.transaction_id=gd.transaction_id 
   and substr(gd.step_id,2,3)=ls.mini)

after this I join it to my global query but generation time increase 2 mins per 200 records so I need to optimize it. I believe that helped me optimize it.

The above isn't a complete query. We also need table and index definitions, explain/execution plan - and a tag for the dbms you're using.

you're using a function on a join which means it can't use indexes (read this is going to be slow) unless substr(gd.step_id,2,3) is a function based index somewhere.  This could potentially be accomplished with a cross/ apply or lateral table value function instead of a join. (Depending on RDBMS)

You can just use a window function to filter the lowest status. Assuming you are using MySQL.
WITH data AS (
  SELECT
    transaction_id,
    step_id,
    string_value,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(
      PARTITION BY transaction_id
      ORDER BY CAST(SUBSTR(status, 2, 3) AS SIGNED)
      ) AS rn
  FROM global_data
)

SELECT * FROM data
WHERE rn = 1


Thank you for answer. I thought about it but is it faster ?

Why not simply try out?
